# Primitives data types overflow in Java

Tags: java

```
int num=Integer.MAX_VALUE*Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Why does this line not give an error of incompatibility in Java because the result is overflow the limit of `int`?

Can someone elaborate?

Comment: why do you expect that to be an exception ?

Comment: because int data type store limit is 2147483647

Comment: and what is the value of `num` when you print it ? I am sure it is within the legal bounds. The value *flowed* over the boundary and wrapped around into negative values.

Comment: When i compile the program it shows value of num is 1

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication operator `*` allows this.  [Section 15.17.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1) states:

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. As a result, if overflow occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the same as the sign of the mathematical product of the two operand values.

In short, with `int` values, overflow is allowed and is not an error.  However, some IDEs may flag this line as a warning (IntelliJ appears to warn about this).  But this compiles, and when I print out `num`, I get `1`, which is the result of the overflow.

Mathematically, define *x* to be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` + 1, or 2<sup>31</sup>.  Then `num` is (x - 1)<sup>2</sup>, or (x<sup>2</sup> -2x + 1).  In Java, when this overflow occurs, it's as if the result is taken (mod 2<sup>32</sup>), which evaluates to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The Java language specification gives a precise meaning for calculations that overflow the data type: any operation on ints for example uses the 32 least significant bits of the result. There is no ambiguity, and no reason to throw an exception.